# How to set default browser for PDF reader Evince on Linux?

Tags: linux, pdf, evince

I find this command

```
sudo update-alternatives –config x-www-browser
```

I choose Chrome. It works for xpdf, but [Evince](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evince) still starts Firefox after click.

I feel Linux is not standard. I use [Linux Mint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint) 8 (Helena) LXDE.

Comment: this question is not well phrased , what do you mean that evince starts firefox ? Having seen this, now I am not so sure about my answer.

Comment: I think the question is about which browser starts if you click on a URL in a PDF document.

Comment: For MATE users: http://askubuntu.com/a/533160/10425

Answer (score 18):

As far as I understand LXDE uses xdg to do calls to applications. This command should fix your issue:

To find out which application opens a pdf file :

```
xdg-mime query default application/pdf
```

To set the application to evince

```
xdg-mime default evince.desktop application/pdf
```

This should work if your application is registered to the desktop (i.e. if there is a launcher)

Comment: this should actually be `xdg-mime default evince.desktop application/pdf`

Comment: For me (Debian 10, unwanted default was libreoffice) this didn't work. Instead `xdg-mime default org.gnome.Evince.desktop application/pdf` did the trick.

Answer (score 11):

Solving your issue is like voodoo, even when there are "protocols" regarding how and which applications are supposed to open a specific kind of file. You'll see that they're very inconsistent between systems and different desktop environments.

So there's no really a "right" answer. I had a similar problem with firefox, so I'm giving you my solution:

1. Create a `~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list` if it doesn't exist
2. Add the following

   ```
   [Default Applications]
   application/pdf=evince.desktop;
   ```

   ...or just the last line if there's something before.

Comment: I've heard that `mimeapps.list` is the new filename for freedesktop.org: http://standards.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/mime-apps-spec-1.0.1.html

Comment: It works like Voodoo, magical, but just simply works =)

Answer (score 4):

You can edit your `$HOME/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` file. If this file does not exist, create one.

For illustration's sake, if you want Chromium to be the default browser, add the following line:

```
x-scheme-handler/http=chromium.desktop
```

That's all.

Comment: Worked like a charm on Arch Linux.

Answer (score 4):

I had a reverse problem - I want firefox to open the links, but evince started chromium no matter what.

I used `strace -o /tmp/output evince` to see what functions are called and found this in the log:

```
open("/home/koniu/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop;", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/share/applications/firefox.desktop;", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop;", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/koniu/.local/share/applications/chromium.desktop", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/share/applications/chromium.desktop", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/applications/chromium.desktop", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 16
```

No idea why there's a semicolon included in the firefox.desktop but I created `/home/koniu/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop` with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Firefox
Exec=/usr/bin/firefox %U
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=firefox
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml_xml;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;
StartupNotify=true
```

And now `evince` starts `firefox` as desired.

Answer (score 3):

To change Gnome applications you need to use gconftool:

```
$ gconftool -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/http/command -t string 'chromium-browser %s'
```

To check the changes:

```
$ gconftool -g /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/http/command
```

Other Gnome applications:

```
/desktop/gnome/url-handlers/chrome/command
/desktop/gnome/url-handlers/https/command
/desktop/gnome/url-handlers/http/command
/desktop/gnome/url-handlers/ftp/command
```

Reference:

> http://www.salixos.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=1376&view=print

Comment: you keep telling the guy to setup gnome, but he is using LXDE...

Comment: @g24l: Evince is a GNOME program, though. (However, it doesn't use GConf for URL handlers anymore.)

Answer (score 1):

None of these solutions worked for me.

I had to edit `~/.config/mimeapps.list` and append these rules to the two headers:

```
[Default Applications]
application/pdf=org.gnome.Evince.desktop

[Added Associations]
application/pdf=evince.desktop;org.gnome.Evince.desktop;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the default browser in Gnome applications with `gnome-default-applications-properties`.

Comment: you almost killed my system!

after apt-get gnome-control-center, the system is almost broken.

Comment: define "almost broken"

Comment: The issue may be you are telling him to install gnome stuff when his window manager is probably LXDE.

Comment: i report it:
http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=50017

it write file .xsession-errors with "fcitx signal 11", and eat the hd space.

Comment: @Dan keep in mind that evince *is* "gnome stuff", and has gnome dependencies; that said, I don't know what the right answer here is. (Also, LXDE is a desktop environment, not a window manager, not that matters here.)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, using evince under KDE. I had to log out from KDE, login to GNOME, and set the default browser of GNOME (`Search` -> `Details` -> `Default Applications` -> `Browser`). Then go back to KDE and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question... but none of the answers seem to give the correct answer.

First check that these shell commands:
`xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/http` and `xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/https`
both return `firefox.desktop`

Then to set Evince (any other Gnome apps that encounter a URL) to use chromium instead:

`xdg-mime default chromium-browser.desktop x-scheme-handler/http` and `xdg-mime default chromium-browser.desktop x-scheme-handler/https`